# How to resolve "You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work" Warning?

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, terminal, sass

I am in the process of setting up a new Mac for work. I have installed Grunt & Grunt CLI globally. Then I did a `npm install` inside a project folder to install all dependencies.

No problems so far, but as soon as I try to run the `sass:dist` task, I get this warning:

```
Warning: You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for
this task to work. More info:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass Use --force 
to continue.
```

What I understand is that I need to have Ruby and Sass installed on a more global level for this task to run. As I am still pretty new to working with the terminal, I did a quick search to find out what `PATH` is - seems like its some system path (that can be changed) where important data is stored.

Does this mean I can simply do a `sudo grunt install contrib-sass -g` to resolve the issue? And what about Ruby – I always thought its already installed on OS X?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grunt sass don't have ruby and sass installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269242/grunt-sass-dont-have-ruby-and-sass-installed)

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Ok I got it. I just had to install Sass using `gem install sass` and now everything is fine...couldn't be easier.

Comment: sudo apt-get install ruby-compass : seems to install both on Ubuntu - Ruby wasn't installed in my case

Comment: On my Mac `sudo` was required before `gem install sass`.

Comment: This is the same for Windows

Comment: (Win7) I had to manually add the Ruby bin path into PATH - only afterwards the gem install sass worked.

Answer (score 91):

If you're on OSX El Capitan or Yosemite on Mac there seem to be an issue installing the gem.

Try

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin sass
```

Solution was [from github](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1769).

Comment: Works also on Yosemite.

Comment: Works well for El Capitan !

Answer (score 12):

You need to install Ruby and Sass as:

For Ruby use command

`sudo apt-get install ruby-full`

And for Sass use command

```
sudo gem install sass
```

Comment: I already had ruby installed and only the command sudo gem install sass worked for me.

Comment: just -> gem install sass

Answer (score 8):

grunt-sass documentation is not very clear. To avoid the need of Ruby, you can try this:

npm uninstall --save grunt-contrib-sass

npm install --save node-sass grunt-sass

Try this, It's work for me.

[reference](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass/issues/229)

Comment: This is the best answer in 2020. 
It makes SASS work like a charm and keeps all of the dependencies locally installed via npm.

When adapting my code from grunt-contrib-sass to grunt-sass, I needed to make some adjustments to my grunt config, but their usage example made it easy: https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass#usage

Comment: Great, thanks for the tip! Had been searching how to get rid of that dependency to Ruby and you answered it.
I would however use rather `npm install --save-dev` instead of `--save` because you only need sass for development (I just edited this in the answer).

Comment: But after that, I had to change my Gruntfile.js:

`const sass = require("node-sass");
grunt.initConfig({
sass: {
  options: { implementation: sass }
}`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68104462/6909703

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Ruby and Sass as:

For Ruby use command

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```

And for Sass use command

```
sudo gem install sass
```

Answer (score 1):

Use grunt --force if you are using grunt.
If you want to run an application using grunt and a warning is occur like this. For ignoring this warning you can use --force.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow. You should add some more description to your answer. It is not best practice to post answers with just one sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install Ruby and then Ruby to install SASS. Probably only the best way to do it if you already use Homebrew, or want to start using it regularly...

```
brew install ruby
gem install sass
```

Answer (score 1):

Also simply `brew install saas/sass/sass` on Mac High Sierra (10.13.x)