# Grunt sass don't have ruby and sass installed?

Tags: gruntjs

When I want to use my sass task with grunt I immediately get this error:

Warning: 
You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.
More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
 Use --force to continue.

When I use my project on my Macbook I have no problems but when I use it on my iMac I get this message. I tried reinstalling sass several times by using several methods but none of them seem to work. Anyone has an idea? My iMac is pretty new so I might forgot something?

Thanks in regard!

Comment: grunt-contrib-sass needs ruby in your runtime. What is the output of `ruby --version` from the console?

Comment: It says this:
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

Comment: Alright, how about `sass --version` ?

Comment: Command not found ;)
Anny suggestions? I'm going to look how to install sass in the meanwhile. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just installed sass with sudo gem install sass and now it works! Awesome! Just as I thought.. I was forgetting something. Thanks for helping me dsschnau!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work" Warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176410/how-to-resolve-you-need-to-have-ruby-and-sass-installed-and-in-your-path-for-th)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176410/how-to-resolve-you-need-to-have-ruby-and-sass-installed-and-in-your-path-for-th/48580068#48580068) on how to use grunt sass **without the need to globally install Ruby and sass**.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to install Sass with `sudo gem install sass`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to install sass with npm: `npm install --save-dev sass`

You'll need to invoke `grunt` from a npm script, e.g. running `npm run build` with below configuration in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "grunt build"
}
```

as this allows npm to add node modules who expose a binary(like `sass`) before invoking your `grunt` script.

If you don't like this and don't mind a global, install sass like `npm install -g sass`

Answer (score 0):

I was still getting error while running `sudo gem install sass`.

For me `sudo npm install -g sass` worked.