# Can't install Ruby and sass gem for Mac

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems, gruntjs

sudo gem install sass

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.

**therefore not working grunt watch**

grunt watch
Running "watch" task
Waiting...

> > File "scss/modules/_base.scss" changed.
> >     Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
> >     /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem sass (>= 0.a) with executable sass (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:263:in`bin_path'
> >         from /usr/local/bin/sass:22:in `'
> >     Warning: Exited with error code 1 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
Completed in 1.020s at Tue Dec 04 2018 05:00:37 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) - Waiting...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grunt sass don't have ruby and sass installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269242/grunt-sass-dont-have-ruby-and-sass-installed)

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the xcode dev tools yet? Try this first:

```
xcode-select --install
```

And then install Sass:

```
sudo gem install sass
```

Answer (score 1):

May for only  install it, you can use -n option: `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin sass`

But,i strongly recommends you to use a ruby manager, like RVM (https://rvm.io/rvm/install) supports MacOS, permits you to have multiple Ruby versions and keep all your gems organized by version.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error.

For me running `sudo npm install -g sass` resolved the issue.